# opening ffmpeg/mpeg-4 avi in openCV 3 python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, video, ffmpeg

I am stuck trying to open a mpeg4 video file in openCV. The video file was generated in ffmpeg using this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -s 2048x2048 -r 30 -pix_fmt gray -i \\.\pipe\pipe1 -qv 5 -vcodec mpeg4 out.avi
```

now I am trying to open the file like this

```
import cv2
#avi_path is full path to avi
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(avi_path)
img1=cap.read()
```

but this returns: False, none

The same procedure works fine if I use libxvid for encoding instead but I want to use mpeg4 because it encodes faster (I need to encode several streams simultaneously).

Should openCV be able to open the mpeg4 encoded avi file?

I am using openCV3 and python 2.7 under Windows 64bit

I am also attaching GSpot panels of one video encoded in xvid (left) which I can open. And one video encoded in mpeg4 (right) which I cannot open.
[image]
I have a suspicion that some LAV splitter/decoder settings may interfere ?! - but I don't understand enough of that to get to the bottom of it.

This is my ffprobe output for the mpeg4 file encoded with the additional ffmpeg parameter '-vtag xvid' as suggested in a comment by Mulvya

```
  ffprobe version N-75474-g74e4948 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavcodec     57.  3.100 / 57.  3.100
  libavformat    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6.  6.100 /  6.  6.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, avi, from 'out1b.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.2.100
  Duration: 00:00:23.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2049 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (Simple Profile) (xvid / 0x64697678), yuv420p, 2048x2048 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], 2044 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
```

Comment: Try adding `-vtag xvid` as an output option to the ffmpeg command

Comment: unfortunately not working for me

Comment: Paste  ffprobe for the file tagged with xvid

Comment: pasted to original post

Comment: Sorry, also for the working AVI.

Comment: Never mind my comment to your suggestion. Adding -vtag xvid IS working for me! Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?
Also, why does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-vtag xvid` as an output option to the ffmpeg command

The codec tag tells the player/processor which decoder to use for the input video stream. Although XVid and MPEG4 are encoders of the same codec, maybe OpenCV doesn't recognize videos tagged as `mpeg4`.

Answer (score 0):

or you can do something else which I figured out by coincidence:

First, of course you know the version of your OpenCV ex: 2.4.11

Then go to C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin , copy opencv_ffmpeg2411.dll , and paste it in the root directory of Python ex: C:\Python27

** if the dll file is opencv_ffmpeg.dll only without the version, you should type it yourself to be opencv_ffmpeg(your version without dots).dll

Voila.

hope I helped

Comment: I found opencv_ffmpeg2412_64.dll
I copied it to the python27 folder and renamed it to opencv_ffmpeg300.dll and opencv_ffmpeg300_64.dll but it is not working

Comment: @jlarsch Try downloading this http://originaldll.com/file/ffmpeg.dll/17422.html file and doing the same steps mentioned before.  If it didn't work, try copying and pasting the original DLL file as is. Tell me if something changes

Comment: @jlarsch There is something weird btw, from your previous comment it seems that the OpenCV version installed on your PC is 3.0.0, however you found the DLL file name opencv_ffmpeg2412_64.dll, which is weird because when you extract OpenCV it comes with its compatible DLL file, but try what I wrote in the previous comment and keep me updated.

Comment: thanks! this turned out to be unnecessary. The existing dll works as long as I set the parameter -vtag xvid